# strncmp proper usage

Tags: c

Here's the quick background:  I've got a client and a server program that are communicating with each other over a Unix socket.  When parsing the received messages on the server side, I am attempting to use strncmp to figure out what action to take.

The problem I'm having is figuring out exactly what to use for the length argument of strncmp.  The reason this is being problematic is that some of my messages share a common prefix.  For example, I have a message "getPrimary", which causes the server to respond with a primary server address, and a message "getPrimaryStatus", which causes the server to respond with the status of the primary server.  My initial thought was to do the following:

```
if(strncmp(message,"getPrimary",strlen("getPrimary"))==0){
    return foo;
}
else if(strncmp(message,"getPrimaryStatus",strlen("getPrimaryStatus"))==0){
    return bar;
}
```

The problem with this is when I send the server "getPrimaryStatus", the code will always return foo because strncmp is not checking far enough in the string.  I could pass in strlen(message) as the length argument to strncmp, but this seems to defeat the purpose of using strncmp, which is to prevent overflow in the case of unexpected input.  I do have a static variable for the maximum message length I can read, but it seems like passing this in as the length is only making sure that if the message overflows, the effects are minimized.

I've come up with a few solutions, but they aren't very pretty, so I was wondering if there was a common way of dealing with this problem.

For reference, my current solutions are:
Order my if / else if statements in such a way that that any messages with common prefixes are checked in order of descending length (which seems like a really good way to throw a landmine in my code for anyone trying to add something to it later on).

Group my messages with common prefixes together and look for the suffix first:

```
if(strncmp(message,"getPrimary",strlen("getPrimary"))==0){
    if(strncmp(message,"getPrimaryStatus",strlen("getPrimaryStatus"))==0){
        return bar;
    else
        return foo;
    }
}
```

But this just feels messy, especially since I have about 20 different possible messages that I'm handling.

Create an array of all the possible messages I have, add a function to my init sequence that will order the array by descending length, and have my code search through the elements of that list until it finds a match.  This seems complicated and silly.

It seems like this should be a common enough issue that there ought to be a solution for it somewhere, but I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming that the string in `message` is *supposed* to be null-terminated, the only reason to use `strncmp()` here rather than `strcmp()` would be to be to prevent it looking beyond the end of `message`, in the case where `message` is *not* null-terminated.

As such, the `n` you pass to `strncmp()` should be the received size of `message`, which you ought to know (from the return value of the `read()` / `recv()` function that read the message).

Comment: Looks like this is the simplest solution.  This is actually my first time using Unix sockets to facilitate inter-process communication, and I wrote the socket handling code about two months ago... I had completely forgotten that I was using read(), which returns the number of bytes read!

Comment: I believe that passing the message size to strncmp instead is an incomplete solution to your problem.  Please see my solution for details.

Comment: Comparisons between strings with many matching characters can most efficiently performed using a "chunking" approach, while comparisons between strings that differ early on may be more efficient using a character-at-a-time approach.  I wouldn't be surprised if some implementations of strncmp use chunking when "n" is large, though it would be better if there were separate functions for the use cases where matching is likely versus those where it's unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to compare the longest names first - order the tests (or the table containing the keywords) so that the longer names precede the shorter.  However, taking your example:

```
GetPrimaryStatus
GetPrimary
```

You probably want to ensure that `GetPrimaryIgnition` is not recognized as `GetPrimary`.  So you really need to compare using the length of the longer of the two strings - the message or the keyword.

Your data structure here might be:

```
static const struct
{
    char   *name;
    size_t  name_len;
    int     retval;
} Messages[] =
{
    { "getPrimaryStatus", sizeof("getPrimaryStatus"), CMD_PRIMARYSTATUS },
    { "getPrimary",       sizeof("getPrimary"),       CMD_PRIMARY       },
    ...
};
```

You can then loop through this table to find the relevant command.  With some care you can limit the range that you have to look at.  Note that the `sizeof()` values include the NUL at the end of the string.  This is useful if you can null terminate your message

However, it is by far simplest if you can null terminate the command word in the message, either by copying the message somewhere or by modifying the message in situ.  You then use `strcmp()` instead of `strncmp()`.  A Shortest Unique Prefix lookup is harder to code.

One plausible way of finding the command word is with `strcspn()` - assuming your commands are all alphabetic or alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

I sense that you are using strncmp to prevent buffer overflow, however, the message is already copied into memory (i.e. the message buffer).  Also, the prototype

```
int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num );
```

indicates that the function has no side effects (i.e. it does not change either input buffer) so there should be no risk that it will overwrite the buffer and change memory.  (This is not the case for strcpy(). )

You could make sure that the length of your message buffer is longer than your longest command string.  That way you are sure that you are always accessing memory that you own.

Also, if you insist on using strncmp you could store your list of commands in an array and sort it from largest to smallest. You could associate each string with a length (and possibly a function pointer to execute a handler).

Finally, you could find a C version of what C++ calls a map or what Ruby or PHP call associative arrays.  This lets library handle this if-else tree for you efficiently and correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `strncmp()`. Use `strlcmp()` instead. It's safer.

Comment: strlcmp() doesn't seem to be part of any standard; and if the implementations I found online are typical, then its behavior degenerates to strncmp()'s behavior if one string is a subset of the other. That's exactly what the OP does not want.

Answer (score 0):

Does your message contain just one of these commands, or a command string followed by whitespace/open-parenthesis/etc.?

If it's the former, drop `strncmp` and just use `strcmp`.

If it's the latter, simply check `isspace(message[strlen(command)])` or `message[strlen(command)]=='('` or similar. (Note: `strlen(command)` is a constant and you should probably write it as such, or use a macro to get it from the size of the string literal.)

Comment: Use: `sizeof("KeyWord")-1` - because `sizeof()` counts the terminal null too.  It's a compile-time constant, of course.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have mentioned all that.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way to use strncmp to determine if two strings are equal is to verify beforehand that the strings have the same length:

```
/* len is a placeholder for whatever variable or function you use to get the length */
if ((len(a) == len(b)) && (strncmp(a, b, len(a)) == 0))
{
    /* Strings are equal */
}
```

Otherwise you will match to something longer or shorter than your comparison:

`strncmp(a, "test", strlen("test"))` matches "testing", "test and a whole bunch of other characters", ect.

`strncmp(a, "test", strlen(a))` matches "", "t", "te", "tes".

Comment: But the problem is that we can not guarantee `s1` is a valid NUL-terminated string, that is the meaning of `n`

Answer (score 0):

Use strcmp, but also compare the lengths of the two strings. If the lengths are identical, then strcmp will give you the result you seek.

Answer (score -1):

Digging out from my memory doing C programming a year ago, I think the third argument is supposed to tell the function how many characters to process for the comparison. That's why it's safe as you have control over how many characters to process

So should be something like:

```
if(strncmp(message, "getPrimary", strlen("getPrimary")) {
   //
}
```